# Divide each thread to use ID in a particular range

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a project in which I need to make sure each thread get's unique `ID` every time in a particular range. For example-

If `number of threads is 2` and `number of tasks is 10` then each thread will be performing 10 tasks. So that means 2 thread will be doing 20 tasks.

So what I am looking for something like this-

In the above example, first thread should be using `id between 1 and 10` and second thread should be using `id between 11 and 20`.

Another example. So suppose if I have `3 thread` and `number of tasks as 20` then first thread should be using ID between `1 and 20` and second thread should be between `21 and 40` and third thread in between `41 and 60`.

Below is the code I have so far, what it does is that it will get id as an `AtomicInteger` and I am getting unique id every time starting from 1.

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private final AtomicInteger id;
    private int noOfTasks;

    public ThreadTask(AtomicInteger id2, int noOfTasks) {
        this.id = id2;
        this.noOfTasks = noOfTasks;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(noOfTasks > 0) {
            System.out.println(id.getAndIncrement());
              // And use this id for other things.
        noOfTasks--;
         }
    }
}

public class XMPTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int noOfThreads = 2;
        final int noOfTasks = 10;

        final AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger(1);

        //create thread pool with given size 
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

        // queue some tasks 
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfThreads; i++) {
            service.submit(new ThreadTask(id, noOfTasks));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I restrict this such that thread 1 should get id between `1 and 10` and second thread should get id between `11 and 20`

**Updated Code:-**
I am trying the below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int noOfThreads = 2;
    final int noOfTasks = 10;

    //create thread pool with given size 
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

    // queue some tasks 
    for (int i = 0, int nextId = 1; i < noOfThreads; i++, nextId += noOfTasks) {
        service.submit(new ThreadTask(nextId, noOfTasks));
    }
}


class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private final int id;
    private int noOfTasks;

    public ThreadTask(int nextId, int noOfTasks) {
        this.id = nextId;
        this.noOfTasks = noOfTasks;
    }

    public void run() {

        for (int i = id; i <= noOfTasks; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

So for the first thread it is printing out 1 - 10 which is fine. But in the second thread, nextId is 11 and noOfTasks is 10 so my for loop going to work in the run method for second time.

Comment: *"I need to make sure each thread get's unique ID every time in a particular range."*  Why?  It has a 'bad code smell' from here.

Comment: I am trying to make sure each thread is working independently on a different range apart from the other threads. As we are planning to do Load and Performance testing so for that this has been told to me by our seniors. Make sure you each thread is assigned a range and it is working in that range only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split up the range however you want in the singlethreaded code before you launch your threads, then pass the range to each thread.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int noOfThreads = 2;
    final int noOfTasks = 10;

    //create thread pool with given size 
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

    // queue some tasks 
    for (int i = 0, int nextId = 1; i < noOfThreads; i++, nextId += noOfTasks) {
        service.submit(new ThreadTask(nextId, noOfTasks));
    }
}

class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private final int id;
    private int noOfTasks;

    public ThreadTask(int nextId, int noOfTasks) {
        this.id = nextId;
        this.noOfTasks = noOfTasks;
    }

    public void run() {

        for (int i = id; i < id + noOfTasks; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is one problem with this code. For the second time, it will be nextId as 11 and numberOftasks as 10. So how my for loop going to workin in the run method? I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: Right, you need to use the id range `[id, id + noOfTasks)`, not `[id, noOfTasks]`.  I've provided the code in my update above.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to increment id, and therefore it cannot be final. 
I also dont see why you need to use AtomicInteger as there is no contention in the Dispatcher thread (the thread processing the main function in this case).
If you still need to use it, this is how I would do it.

```
public class XMPTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int noOfThreads = 2;
    final int noOfTasks = 10;

    AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger(1);

    //create thread pool with given size 
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

    // queue some tasks 
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfThreads; i++) {
        service.submit(new ThreadTask(id, noOfTasks));
        id.addAndGet(1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I tried this but it printed out 21 as well. It shouldn't be printing out 21 right? And in your example it will make sure first thread will be in range from `1 to 10` and then second thread will be in range from `11 to 20`?

Comment: I found out one problem with his code as well. I have updated the question with my code.